# problem with limit and offset in sql?

Tags: database, postgresql

Well I have a sorted table by id and I want to retrieve n rows offset m rows, but when I use it without orderby it is producing unpredictable results and with order by id its taking too much of time, since my table is already ordered, I just want to retrieve n rows leaving first m rows.

Comment: *since my table is already ordered*. A table is an unordered set of rows. The database gives you no guarantee about the sort of the rows unless you specify an Order By. Thus, there is no concept of "my table is already ordered". You cannot assume that when you query your table it will be in a specific order even given the same query unless you use an Order By.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) says:

> The query planner takes LIMIT into account when generating a query plan, so you are very likely to get different plans (yielding different row orders) depending on what you use for LIMIT and OFFSET. Thus, using different LIMIT/OFFSET values to select different subsets of a query result *will give inconsistent results* unless you enforce a predictable result ordering with ORDER BY. This is not a bug; it is an inherent consequence of the fact that SQL does not promise to deliver the results of a query in any particular order unless ORDER BY is used to constrain the order.

So what you are trying cannot really be done.

I suppose you could play with the planner options or rearrange the query in a clever way to trick the planner into using a plan that suits you, but without actually showing the query, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

You really shouldn't rely on implicit ordering though, because you may not be able to predict the exact order of how data goes into the database.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above, SQL does not guarantee anything about order unless you have an ORDER BY clause. LIMIT can still be useful in such a situation, but I can't think of any use for OFFSET. It sounds like you don't have an index on id, because if you do, the query should be extremely fast, clustered or not. Take another look at that. (Also check CLUSTER, which may improve your performance at the margin.)

REPEAT: this is not something about Postgresql. Its behavior here is conforming.